# Attribute Routing with empty parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm using the following code in `asp core`

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("all/{q:alpha}/{begin:int}/{pageSize:int}/{sortBy:alpha}/{sortOrder:alpha}")]
    public IActionResult GetAll(string q, int begin, int pageSize, string sortBy, bool sortOrder)
    {
        return Json(_repository.GetItemsByPage(q, begin, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder));
    }
```

It should be possible that 'q' is empty. Without the attribute routing everything works fine. The following request is working:

```
http://localhost/api/all/?q=&begin=1&pagesize=3&sortBy=title&sortOrder=false
```

With the attribute routing in place the request is:

```
 http://localhost/api/all//1/3/title/false
```

How to make it work with an empty value (q)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my suggestion optional parameter must come at end.

```
[HttpGet]

[Route("all/{begin:int}/{pageSize:int}/{sortBy:alpha}/{sortOrder:alpha}/{q:alpha}")]
public IActionResult GetAll(string q, int begin, int pageSize, string sortBy, bool sortOrder)
 {
   return Json(_repository.GetItemsByPage(q, begin, pageSize, sortBy, sortOrder));
 }
```

By this your both url will work.

```
http://localhost/api/all/?q=&begin=1&pagesize=3&sortBy=title&sortOrder=false

http://localhost/api/all/1/3/title/false

http://localhost/api/all/1/3/title/false/value of q
```

Now if your method has more than one optional parameter there are multiple way to solve problem.

```
 http://localhost/api/all/1/3/title/false?q=1&optinal2=value
```

Or create second API method.

Comment: thanks. I moved the optional parameter at the end and used: `{q:alpha?}`